# python tkinter не работает код

Tags: python, tkinter

При нажатии левой кнопки мыши текст из entry должен выводиться в label.

Код запускается, но не работает функция нажатия.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Label

window = Tk()
window.title('text')
window.geometry('300x305')

text = ""

label = Label(text="text", fg="yellow", bg="#400080", font="Arial 12", width='100')
entry = Entry(width=100, textvariable=text)

def dec(event):  
    label.config(text=text, fg="blue")

window.bind('<Button-1>', dec)

label.pack()
entry.pack(padx=15, pady=30)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр `textvariable` не работает с простыми переменнымы - сюда нужно передать экземпляр объекта `StringVar`. Прочитать текущее значение этой переменной можно методом `get()`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Entry, Label

window = Tk()
window.title('text')
window.geometry('300x305')

text = StringVar()

label = Label(text="text", fg="yellow", bg="#400080", font="Arial 12", width='100')
entry = Entry(width=100, textvariable=text)


def dec(event):
    label.config(text=text.get(), fg="blue")


window.bind('<Button-1>', dec)

label.pack()
entry.pack(padx=15, pady=30)
window.mainloop()
```

[ссылка на документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables)

Comment: Спасибо большое